# How do I remove all python packages?

Tags: apt, package-management, python, uninstall, pip

I am relatively new to this. I have installed various python2.7 packages, sometimes with apt-get, sometimes with pip, sometimes from source. I am experiencing millions of different issues when trying to remove, upgrade or install a new package. So, I want to remove ALL python packages, and start with a clean installation. Is there a relatively safe way to do this?

Comment: At the moment you succeed to uninstall *all* python packages, your system is unusable. You won't be able to do any basic action, including installing/uninstalling.

Comment: So reinstall ubuntu then? Or is there a way to identify the packages which will not crash my system

Comment: Look into /var/log/apt , there's bunch of history logs. Read through them using less and zless commands and find what packages you installed. But if you don't mind reinstalling then do that - simplest way

Comment: @Serg then there is pip, I never use that, not sure what it does and where. > reinstalling seems best.

Comment: @jacobvlijm pip is like apt but only for Python. I am not sure if it will remove what was installed via apt though.

Comment: @Serg pip won't remove apt-stuff but works in `/usr/local/lib/python*/` instead - per default at least. If one would force it to `/usr/lib/` anything might happen :-D

Comment: Remove all packages inside `/usr/local/lib/python[your-version-here]`.  You can either `rm -r` contents of that directory or use `pip uninstall <package name>`

Comment: @Ron you probably mean /usr/local/lib/python[your-version-here]/dist-packages. The problem is that pip does not see packages installed from source or with apt, and since this has been going on for more than a year, i really do not know which one was installed with what method. I have fixed the problem for now, managed to re install the libraries that I need for now, I will backup my scripts, and wait for the impending armageddon before I re-install ubuntu. Jacob, Serg, Phillip and Ron, thanks

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy See below answer...

Comment: Now that I have read this question 3 times very very slowly, what pops  out is " I am experiencing millions of different issues when trying to remove, upgrade or install a new package", which is clearly an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)  and absolutely no clarity on what millions of issues appear and what method they use to deal with packages.

Answer (score 3):

## Warning!

#### This is an answer to your question!

`pip` has an option that allows you to *process an uninstall without confirmation: `--yes`.* **So if you get all packages and then execute them one by one with the uninstaller, you'll remove all of them.**

To do that you can use the `xargs` command: it will allow you to use `\n` as a separator (see [man xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) for more information)

so all that together is just one command that *will remove all of the installed Python packages*::

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall --yes
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip)

Comment: OK, but should be noted this is a very unforgiving approach. I've installed `pip3` from scratch and `pip3 freeze` showed list packages even before I installed anything at all, which tells me this may remove more than one actually needs, i.e. not just stuff OP themselves installed via `pip install <package>`.

Comment: It's what he asked for, no?  **Remove all Python packages?**

Comment: OP doesn't always know what they ask and what sort of implications it may have.  Not saying it's a wrong interpretation, just giving a word of caution.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Warning added!  :-)